# Relative positioning issue with the bar3d plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm new to Stack Overflow, so my image attachment is not previewed, but [you can see it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3F6C3.jpg).

Basically, I'm using `matplotlib`'s `bar3d` function to plot a probability distribution at different points of time. The issue is that the first 'slice' is positioned above the remaining slices, which obviously is not right. The second and higher numbered slices are positioned correctly with respect to their neighbors.

The only way to avoid this issue is to change the view angle so that there is no intersection between the first and other slices, but that view doesn't capture the point I'm trying to make.

Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this issue? Or is this some kind of a bug that `bar3d` has?

Thanks!

**EDIT: Here's the code**

```
def bar_plot (data, n_slices, dx = 1, dy = 1, z_max = 1, x_label = 'x',
              y_label='y', z_label='z', elev_angle = 30, azim_angle = 115):
    """
    Makes a 3d bar plot of the data given as a 2d numpy array.

    Parameters
    ----------
    data: 2d-array
        Two-dimensional numpy array of z-values
    n_slices: int
        Number of 'slices' in y-directions to be used in the 3D plot
    dx: float
        Distance between neighboring x-positions
    dy: float
        Distance between neighboring y-positions
    x_label: str
        Label of the x-axis
    y_label: str
        Label of the y-axis
    z_lable: str
        Label of the z-axis
    elev_angle: int
        Alevation viewing angle
    azim_angle: int
        Azimuthal viewing angle
    z_max: float
        Default limit to the z-axis

    Returns
    -------
    fig: pyplot figure object
        Figure of the 3d-plot

    ax: pyplot axes object
        Axes object that contains the figure elements
    """

    # Initialize the figure object
    fig = plt.figure(figsize = [10, 8])
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

    # Colors to indicate variation in y-axis
    colors = sns.color_palette('viridis', n_colors=n_slices+1)

    # Dimensions of the 2d-array
    x_length, y_length = data.shape

    # Initial index of the slice
    i_slice = 0

    # Iterate through each slice and add bar plots
    for y in np.arange(0, y_length, y_length//n_slices):

        # x-, y- and z-positions
        x_pos = np.arange(x_length)*dx
        y_pos = y*np.ones(x_length)*dy
        z_pos = np.zeros(x_length)

        # Horizontal dimensions of the bars
        delta_x = dx*np.ones(x_length)
        delta_y = 2*dy*np.ones(x_length)

        # Heights in the z-direction
        delta_z = p[:,y]

        ax.bar3d(x_pos, y_pos, z_pos, delta_x, delta_y, delta_z, 
                 color = colors[i_slice])

        i_slice = i_slice + 1;

    # Add axis labels
    ax.set_xlabel(x_label)
    ax.set_ylabel(y_label)
    ax.set_zlabel(z_label)

    # Adjust the 3d viewing angle of the plot
    ax.view_init(elev_angle, azim_angle)

    # Set the z-limit of the plot
    z_max = np.min([z_max, np.max(data)])
    ax.set_zlim([0, z_max])

    return fig, ax
```

Comment: Where is the code ?

Comment: I think this is the usual issue of [My 3D plot doesn’t look right at certain viewing angles](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/faq.html). One may consider it as a bug, but essentially it is simply that matplotlib has never been designed for 3D purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @ImportanceOfBeingErnest! Apparently, it is a "bug" and there's not much I can do about it.

Comment: @SachinKukreja I posted the code. Sorry for missing it. Any thoughts?